# D3 Multiples with linked focus/mouseover tooltip: Crosshair focus line not fitting to x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to combine [this multiples example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1157787) with focus mouseover + crosshair functionality seen in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3). My intended y-sized crosshair line keeps shooting over the x line. [See working Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UVYRtTs40Jn6MyII8sDl?p=preview).
My Problem seems to be in this part of the code (see from line 227) where I am trying to set the end point of the focus line relatively with the yScale and yDomain.

```
var yDomain = d3.extent(d.values, function(d) { return d.price; });

            focus.select('#focusLineX')
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y2", ys[d.key](yDomain[0]));
```

However I am not quite getting the hang of it. Here is my complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .area {
    //fill: #e7e7e7;
    fill: transparent;
  }

  .overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .focus circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    r: 4.5;
  }

  .focusLine {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 45,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 961 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 138 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse,
      bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }).left,
      formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
      formatDate = d3.time.format("%X"),
      formatCurrency = function(d) {
        return formatValue(d);
      };

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    // variable to hold our yscales
    var ys = {};

    var area = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return ys[d.symbol](d.price); //<-- call the y function matched to our symbol
      });

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d, i) {
        return ys[d.symbol](d.price); //<-- call the y scale function matched to our symbol
      });

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x) // x is the d3.time.scale()
      .orient("bottom") // the ticks go below the graph
      .ticks(4) // specify the number of ticks
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

    d3.csv("stocks_chart_komplett.csv", type, function(error, data) {

      // Nest data by symbol.
      var symbols = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {          
          return d.symbol;
        })
        .entries(data);

      // Compute the maximum price per symbol, needed for the y-domain.
      symbols.forEach(function(s) {
        var maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) {
          return d.price;
        });
        ys[s.key] = d3.scale.linear() //<-- create a scale for each "symbol" (ie Sensor 1, etc...)
          .range([height, 0])
          .domain([0, maxPrice]);
      });

      // Compute the minimum and maximum date across symbols.
      // We assume values are sorted by date.
      x.domain([
        d3.min(symbols, function(s) {
          return s.values[0].date;
        }),
        d3.max(symbols, function(s) {
          return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date;
        })
      ]);

      // Add an SVG element for each symbol, with the desired dimensions and margin.
      var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        .data(symbols)
        .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      // Add the area path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d",area);

      // Add the line path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        });

      // Add a small label for the symbol name.
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 6)
        .attr("y", height - 6)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) {
          return "<"+d.key+"> value now: "+d.values[d.values.length - 1].price+" "+d.values[d.values.length - 1].unit;
        });

      svg.append('g') // create a <g> element
        .attr('class', 'x axis') // specify classes
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis); // let the axis do its thing

      // build 4 y axis
      var axisGs = svg.append("g"); //<-- create a collection of axisGs

      axisGs
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.values[d.values.length - 1].unit;
        });

      axisGs.each(function(d, i) { //<-- for each axisG create an axis with it's scale
        var self = d3.select(this);
        self.call(
          d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(ys[d.key])
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(4)
        );
      });

      var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .style("display", "none");

       focus.append("circle")

      focus.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", "-.90em")
        .style("font-size","12px")
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");

      svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("mouseover", function() {
          focus.style("display", null);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
          focus.style("display", "none");
        })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);

        // append the x line
        focus.append("line")
            .attr('id', 'focusLineX')
            .attr("class", "focusLine");

        // append the y line
        focus.append("line")
            .attr('id', 'focusLineY')
            .attr("class", "focusLine");

      function mousemove() {
        var date, index,index_diff;
        date = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        var focus = svg.selectAll(".focus");
        focus.attr("transform", function(d) {

            index = bisectDate(d.values, date, 0, d.values.length - 1);

            var yDomain = d3.extent(d.values, function(d) { return d.price; });

            focus.select('#focusLineX')
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y2", ys[d.key](yDomain[0]));


            console.log(yDomain[0]);

            //.attr("y2", ys[d.key]);

            // focus.select('#focusLineY')
            // .attr("x1", -width)
            // .attr("y1", 0)
            // .attr("x2", width)
            // .attr("y2", 0);

           //console.log(index, d.values[index].symbol, d.values[index].date, d.values[index].price);
            focus.selectAll("text").text(function (d){

                return (""+formatDate(d.values[index].date)+", "+d.values[index].price+"")
            });
          // adjust mouseover to use appropriate scale
          return "translate(" + x(d.values[index].date) + "," + ys[d.key](d.values[index].price) + ")"
        });
      }
    });

    function type(d) {
      d.price = +d.price;
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      return d;
    }
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of svg:clipPath. I have made a clipPath which restricts to the area which consists the line chart excluding the x and y axis.

The reason for the line coming over is `yDomain[0]` is the max y of the line, and you are translating this line such that it comes up on the proper place, but you will not be able to handle the extra line which shoots outside the x axis.

```
focus.select('#focusLineX')
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y2", ys[d.key](yDomain[0]));
```

I have updated the code with clip path, here is the [fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDXlLoMTrNRavyQdEZME?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick fix! Would never had thought of that! This workaround however is problem-prone because it also clips focus/tooltip-objects that have to go over the axis lines (for example when having Ymin/Ymax values displayed. I would still very much like to find the solution for addressing the right focus line start/endpoint for the right multiple chart